# Rails Post request through JS

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have one page (Filter Page) with button which have onClick() call to, searchProductsWithParams() script function, the button is,

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg mt-4 py-3 px-5" onclick="searchProductsWithParams()">SEARCH</button>
```

Now the script function on the same page (Filter Page) is,

```
function searchProductsWithParams(){
shapesId = [1,2,3]
  colorsId = [1,2,3]
  $.ajax({
    url: '/products/product_list_with_filter_params',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
      shape_ids: shapesId,
      color_ids: colorsId,
      }
    });
}
```

This js function is being called by onClick(), event of a button on the page.

Now, I have a controller, products_controller.rb, where I have two actions,
1.index and 2.product_list_with_filter_params

```
def index
  @products = Product.all
  @view_for = "Products"
end

def product_list_with_filter_params
  @products = Product.filter_by_ids(product_filter_ids_params(params))
  @view_for = "Products"
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render :index }
  end
end
```

What I am doing is doing some operations based on the body params in second method, and now what I want is to get the index.html page with the @products, But rather my page is not redirecting and sticked to that previous page only.
The Log record is below,

```
Started POST "/products/product_list_with_filter_params" for ::1 at 2020-05-11 20:40:51 +0530
Processing by ProductsController#product_list_with_filter_params as */*
  Parameters: {"shape_ids"=>["all"], "color_ids"=>["all"]}
User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/application_controller.rb:9
  Rendering products/index.html.erb within layouts/application
Product Load (3.9ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."is_active" = $1 AND "products"."shape" = $2 AND "products"."color" = $3
[["is_active", true], ["shape", 0]]

↳ app/views/products/index.html.erb:123
  Rendered products/index.html.erb within layouts/application (8.0ms)
  Cart Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "carts".* FROM "carts" WHERE "carts"."user_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["user_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/layouts/_new_header.html.erb:57
  Rendered layouts/_new_header.html.erb (3.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 129ms (Views: 105.7ms | ActiveRecord: 8.1ms)
```

Now, What I want is to hit product_list_with_filter_params() method gets executed and render index.html page. I know its not a tricky question but I am always confused with AJAX.

Plz, Comment if more detail required?

Comment: An ajax request does not redirect the brower. Thats kind of the whole point.Here you are sending a request but you don't have a success handler to do anything with the response.

Answer (score 0):

As max has pointed out, AJAX does not redirect the browser, instead it will return a response and you decide what you want to do from there. AJAX is useful if you want to perform a request without changing the page you are on.

Also to point out, instead of having 2 end points that does about the same thing, you may want to consider just using the `index` endpoint to both get all and filter through `Product`.